# How do I filter to rows of strings that contain a value from a list in Polars

Tags: contains, python-polars, isin

If you had a list of values and a Polars dataframe with a column of text. And you wanted to filter to only the rows containing items from the list, how would you write that?

```py
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'col1': [
        'I am just a string', 
        'one more, but without the letters', 
        'we want, a, b, c,', 
        'Nothing here'
    ]
})
```

Expected output:

```py
shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ col1                              │
│ ---                               │
│ str                               │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ I am just a string                │
│ one more, but without the letter… │
│ we want, a, b, c,                 │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

I assume it'd have something combining/using `.is_in(a_list)` and `.str.contains()`, but I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: df.filter(pl.col(‘col1’).str.contains(‘|’.join(a_list)) worked, courtesy of Hussain

Comment: Slightly different, but [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77323928/in-polars-is-there-a-better-way-to-only-return-items-within-a-string-if-they-ma/77324663#77324663). Completely missed @jqurious's comment here, but now updating my notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use contains_any(), like:

```
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['I am just a string', 'one more, but without the letters', 'we want, a, b, c,', 'Nothing here']
})

df.filter(pl.col('col1').str.contains_any(a_list))
```

This method is more polars-like, and easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

To filter the rows in the Polars dataframe df where the column col1 contains any of the values from the list a_list, you can use the str.contains() method along with the | operator to check for multiple values. Here's the code to do that:

```
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['I am just a string', 'one more, but without the letters', 'we want, a, b, c,', 'Nothing here']
})

mask = df.filter(pl.col('col1').str.contains('|'.join(a_list)) 
filtered_df = df[mask]
```