# In Polars, is there a better way to only return items within a string if they match items in a list using .is_in?

Tags: arraylist, python-polars, .when, isin

Is there a better way to only return each `pl.element()` in a polars array if it matches an item contained within a list?

While it works, I get the error `The predicate 'col("").is_in([Series])' in 'when->then->otherwise' is not a valid aggregation and might produce a different number of rows than the group_by operation would. This behavior is experimental and may be subject to change` warning which leads me to believe there's probably a more concise/better way:

```py
import polars as pl

terms = ['a', 'z']

(pl.LazyFrame({'a':['x y z']})
   .select(pl.col('a')
             .str.split(' ')
             .list.eval(pl.when(pl.element().is_in(terms))
                          .then(pl.element())
                          .otherwise(None))
             .list.drop_nulls()
             .list.join(' ')
           )
   .fetch()
 )
```

For posterity's sake, it replaces my previous attempt using `.map_elements()`:

```py
import polars as pl
import re

terms = ['a', 'z']

(pl.LazyFrame({'a':['x y z']})
   .select(pl.col('a')
             .str.split(' ')
             .map_elements(lambda x: ' '.join(list(set(re.findall('|'.join(terms), x)))),
                           return_dtype = pl.Utf8)
           )
   .fetch()
 )
```

Comment: You can use `.filter()` inside `list.eval()` e.g. `.list.eval(pl.element().filter(pl.element().is_in(terms))).list.join(' ')` - there's also `pl.col("a").str.split(" ").list.set_intersection(terms).list.join(" ")` - but that assumes a term doesn't repeat and not sure if it retains order of the input. Is the goal to remove all "words" from a string column that are not contained inside the `terms` list?

Comment: Those are great! It seems the `.set_intersection()` is the fastest, but didn't like being passed a set. Goal is to show if a column has any keywords that I care about - duplicates aren't a problem, though I'll probably use a `.unique()`

Comment: I probably phrased that badly, if you had `'x y z z'` then `.set_intersection()` will produce only `z` - so possible duplicates in the input are not retained - but that is what you actually want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jqurious and @Dean MacGregor were exactly right, I just wanted to post an solution that explained the differences succinctly:

```py
terms = ['a', 'z']

(pl.LazyFrame({'a':['x a y zebra']})
   .with_columns(only_whole_terms = pl.col('a')
                                      .str.split(' ')
                                      .list.set_intersection(terms),
                 each_term = pl.col('a').str.extract_all('|'.join(terms)),
                )
   .fetch()
)

shape: (1, 3)
┌─────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ a           ┆ only_whole_terms ┆ each_term       │
│ ---         ┆ ---              ┆ ---             │
│ str         ┆ list[str]        ┆ list[str]       │
╞═════════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ x a y zebra ┆ ["a"]            ┆ ["a", "z", "a"] │
└─────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

Also, [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77389199/make-column-of-all-matching-substrings-from-a-list-that-are-found-within-a-polar) adds a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the tricks that @jqurious listed in comments you could also do a regex extract. This started simple but got a little bit clunky as I tried different things. The good thing about the rust regex engine is that it is very performant. The bad thing is that it doesn't have look-arounds so working around that makes it look clunky.

Without look arounds, to ensure we didn't take the z from zebra I had to extract the space before and after a term. Of course there's no space before the first letter and no space after the last letter so that's why I concat a space before and after the initial column. Additionally, to ensure it could capture two letters in a row, I had to replace all single spaces with double spaces which get replaced back to single spaces after the extract step.

```
terms = ['a', 'z', 'x']
termsre = "(" + "|".join([f" {x} " for x in terms]) + ")"
(pl.LazyFrame({'a':['x y z z zebra a', 'x y z', 'a b c']})
 .with_columns(
     b = (pl.lit(" ") + pl.col('a')
       .str.replace_all(" ", "  ") + pl.lit(" "))
       .str.extract_all(termsre)
       .list.join('')
       .str.replace_all("  "," ")
       .str.strip_chars()
 )
 .collect()
)
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────────────┬─────────┐
│ a               ┆ b       │
│ ---             ┆ ---     │
│ str             ┆ str     │
╞═════════════════╪═════════╡
│ x y z z zebra a ┆ x z z a │
│ x y z           ┆ x z     │
│ a b c           ┆ a       │
└─────────────────┴─────────┘
```

Sidenote, `fetch` is for debugging with a limited number of rows. You generally want to be using `collect`

Comment: As OP mentioned speed in one of the comments, I wonder if it would be faster to `.explode()` after the `.str.split()` and do it at the frame/join level? I think I recall some of your previous answers having faster results that way over using the List API.

Comment: It's not the `.list` api in general. It's just `.list.eval` that is the dog. I'm guessing  `set_intersection` is fastest but yeah with_row_count/explode/filter/group_by/agg would be faster than their `.list.eval`.

Comment: I have a case where list.eval(pl.element.map_dict) is so much faster then .explode() on its own.

Comment: @elgreco well that's why benchmarks are important I guess.

Comment: It's really good to know about Rust's regex engine, I'll probably need that sometime soon, but I think I favor the readability of the `set_intersection` unless the gains are too good to pass up (but it seems just slightly slower on my thrown-together test - but still faster than what I had before: 673us, 741us, 1.03ms)