# Make column of all matching substrings from a list that are found within a Polars string column

Tags: string, list, python-polars, findall, set-intersection

How do I return a column of all matching terms or substrings found within a string? I suspect there's a way to do it with `pl.any_horizontal()` as suggested [in these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75831457/how-do-i-filter-to-rows-of-strings-that-contain-a-value-from-a-list-in-polars) but I can't quite piece it together.

```py
import re

terms = ['a', 'This', 'e']

(pl.DataFrame({'col': 'This is a sentence'})
   .with_columns(matched_terms = pl.col('col').map_elements(lambda x: list(set(re.findall('|'.join(terms), x)))))
)
```

The column should return: ['a', 'This', 'e']

EDIT:
The winning solution here: `.str.extract_all('|'.join(terms)).list.unique()` is different from [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77323928/in-polars-is-there-a-better-way-to-only-return-items-within-a-string-if-they-ma/77324663#77324663)'s winning solution: `pl.col('col').str.split(' ').list.set_intersection(terms)`  because `.set_intersection()` doesn't get sub-strings of list elements (such as partial, not full, words).

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of your own question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77323928/in-polars-is-there-a-better-way-to-only-return-items-within-a-string-if-they-ma/77324663#77324663

Comment: It's a Monday, so it may very well be a duplicate, but I believe the difference is: that was seeing which terms were matching whole values in a list, whereas this accounts for substrings once the words are split. That question is about finding list elements in a new list, whereas this is finding the opposite direction, if any of the new list items are contained in the string. That matches on the full term, whereas this question seeks to match substrings. Probably similar methodology. I'll delete if it is duplicate though. Your regex answer might cover this case though.

Comment: As @DeanMacGregor pointed out, `.str.extract_all` can be used instead of `re.findall` if you want to build a single regex: `pl.select(pl.lit('This is a sentence').str.extract_all('This|a|e'))` - Perhaps one step missing from your example `re.escape` - Polars doesn't expose `regex::escape()` it seems. If it did, one could build the regex in Polars which could be useful e.g.  `pl.lit(terms).str.regex_escape().str.concat("|")`

Comment: Thank you, the `.str.extract_all('|'.join(terms)).list.unique()` worked exactly for what I needed, and while slower than the `.set_intersection`, it did work for what this question needed, which was different enough to not be satisfied by my other question, as well as faster than the old solution I had (I'm working with 41k terms - which are sometimes only substrings -across 12mil rows)

Comment: It can get a bit fuzzy because *"Is this a substring?"* and *"Does this text contain this exact **word**?"* are different questions but sometimes people use them interchangeably. Interesting to know `.set_intersection()` wins out for your use-case.

Comment: I think it would be reasonable for you to post the solution provided in the edit as solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've included the accompanying term-matching columns, but the **each_term** column with `pl.col('a').str.extract_all('|'.join(terms))` was the best solution for me.

```py
pl.Config.set_fmt_table_cell_list_len(4)

terms = ['A', 'u', 'bug', 'g']

(pl.DataFrame({'a': 'A bug in a rug.'})
 .select(has_term = pl.col('a').str.contains_any(terms),
         has_term2 = pl.col('a').str.contains('|'.join(terms)),
         has_term3 = pl.any_horizontal(pl.col("a").str.contains(t) for t in terms),
         
         each_term = pl.col('a').str.extract_all('|'.join(terms)),
         
         whole_terms = pl.col('a').str.split(' ').list.set_intersection(terms),
         n_matched_terms = pl.col('a').str.count_matches('|'.join(terms)),
        )
)

shape: (1, 6)
┌──────────┬───────────┬───────────┬────────────────────────┬──────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ has_term ┆ has_term2 ┆ has_term3 ┆ each_term              ┆ whole_terms  ┆ n_matched_terms │
│ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---                    ┆ ---          ┆ ---             │
│ bool     ┆ bool      ┆ bool      ┆ list[str]              ┆ list[str]    ┆ u32             │
╞══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪════════════════════════╪══════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ true     ┆ true      ┆ true      ┆ ["A", "bug", "u", "g"] ┆ ["A", "bug"] ┆ 4               │
└──────────┴───────────┴───────────┴────────────────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────┘
```